# Android smooth gradient

Tags: android, graphics, gradient, radial-gradients

Am drawing a simple circle in a Canvas on Android.
Now I need to fill it with some gradient colors, but they are no really smooth.
This its what i have done:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    rectF.set(20, 20, this.get_Width() - this.get_Width()/10, this.get_Width() - this.get_Width()/10);
    RadialGradient gradient = new RadialGradient(200, 200, 200, 0xFFFFFFFF,
            0xFF000000, android.graphics.Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setShader(gradient);
    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2, getWidth()/3, getGradient());
    invalidate();
}
```

And this is the result:

[image: readial gradient]

My question is: Is it there some way to make HQ radial gradients?

Comment: I need to refresh my memory, but banding in Android is mostly caused by the pixel format. Make sure you are using ARGB_888 and see if things improve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I should initialize my Paint object as:

```
Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
```

That makes the borders cleaner.

And with the @Waqas answer, make the colors itself smoothers.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to your `Activity` which contains the `View` that does the drawing:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
   super.onAttachedToWindow();
   Window window = getWindow();
   // Eliminates color banding
   window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
}
```

Comment: As you said, that eliminates de color bandgin, but the borders are still "weird"